# DomSanitizer Angular problem when displaying base64 as image

Tags: angular, base64

Problem with DomSanitizer: unsafe:SafeValue must use [property]=binding

I have a property in my model that is:  imageUrl : SafeResourceUrl;
Then I got the base64 I receive from backend and sanitize it like this:

`getSafeUrl(base64 : string) { let url = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+base64; return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url); }`

Then in my HTML I try to display the image with:

```
<p><img [src]= "documento.imageUrl"/></p>
```

I keep getting the unsafe message.

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried everything I found online, but nothing seems to work

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: that is the line I try to display the image:

 <p><img [src]= "documento.imageUrl"/></p>

Answer (score 0):

The error could be due the order of execution of your code, i.e the  is loaded before the domSanitizer had done its part. Try the following:

Declare a variable in your component:

```
safeUrl: SafeResourceUrl;
```

Inject the domSanitizer in the component constructor:

```
constructor(public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer)
```

Call the bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl in the ngOnInit:

```
 ngOnInit() {this.safeUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.yourUrl);}
```

Load safeUrl in the HTML:

```
<img [src]= "safeUrl"/>
```

Comment: I can not do this on ngOnInit, because I receive the data from backend after selecting a service on the page.